# Maintain log using trigger for update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have created following database, tables, and trigger for update to maintain update log. When user modifies name/salary/gender/departmentid then it updates log in 'tblEmployeeAudit' table.

Now, there is a catch, if we are just updating same value which is already updated in system, then there should not an update entry be updated in 'tblEmployeeAudit' table.

For example:- if tblEmployee has EmployeeName Ravi with Id=1 then if update same name then there no log should be updated, but in this it is not happening. Please help me out.

```
Create database learning
use learning

USE [learning]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblEmployee]    Script Date: 11/11/2019 3:54:13 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEmployee](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Salary] [int] NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [DepartmentId] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


USE [learning]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblEmployeeAudit]    Script Date: 11/11/2019 3:54:34 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblEmployeeAudit](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AuditData] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Alter trigger tr_tblEmployee_ForUpdate
on tblEmployee
For Update
As
Begin
    Declare @Id int
    Declare @OldName nvarchar(30),@NewName nvarchar(30)
    Declare @OldSalary int,@NewSalary int
    Declare @OldGender nvarchar(10),@NewGender nvarchar(10)
    Declare @OldDeptId int,@NewDeptId int

    Declare @AuditString nvarchar(1000)

    Select * into #TempTable
    from inserted

    While(Exists(Select Id from #TempTable))
    Begin
        Set @AuditString=''

        Select Top 1 @Id=Id,@NewName=Name,@NewSalary=Salary,@NewGender=Gender,@NewDeptId=DepartmentId from #TempTable

        Select @OldName=Name,@OldSalary=Salary,@OldGender=Gender,@OldDeptId=DepartmentId from deleted where Id=@Id

        Set @AuditString='Employee with Id='+CAST(@Id as nvarchar(4))+' changed '
        if(@OldName<>@NewName)
            Set @AuditString=@AuditString+'NAME from '+@OldName+' to '+@NewName

        if(@OldSalary<>@NewSalary)
            Set @AuditString=@AuditString+'Salary from '+@OldSalary+' to '+@NewSalary

        if(@OldGender<>@NewGender)
            Set @AuditString=@AuditString+'Gender from '+@OldGender+' to '+@NewGender

        if(@OldDeptId<>@NewDeptId)
            Set @AuditString=@AuditString+'DepartmentId from '+@OldDeptId+' to '+@NewDeptId

        insert into tblEmployeeAudit values(@AuditString)
        Delete from #TempTable where Id=@Id

    End

End



   update tblEmployee
    set Name='Joseph' where Id=4
```

Note:- Follow data inserted eventhough, when no mismatching row-updated
Employee with Id=4 changed

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? If 2016 or higher, you should probably check out system-versioned-tables instead of working with triggers for this purpose.

Comment: The main reason is following query is causing insert default line, if any update query is executed. Set @AuditString='Employee with Id='+CAST(@Id as nvarchar(4))+' changed '

Comment: I am using SQL server 2014 version, I believe version won't matter in this

Comment: Just need to check if old and new value are mismatch then before inserting record into tblEmployeeAudit, if yes then it will insert record into tblEmployeeAudit else no action

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating Variables to store the changed values,use the inserted and deleted tables to check if the values has been changed,I think that will fix your problem

select * from inserted i
select * from deleted d

Near * you can  select only the column names for which you want to check the value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first check whether anything is changed, before going to generate AuditString. You can use EXCEPT operator to check the changes.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT Id, Name, Salary, Gender from inserted 
            EXCEPT
            SELECT Id, Name, Salary, Gender from deleted)
BEGIN
-- GO FOR AUDIT LOGIC
END
```

[Read more on EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)